# Is there a way to check for all purchased play store items, consumable or not?

Tags: java, android, google-play-developer-api

First stackoverflow question, let me know if I get anything wrong.

The Google Play Store provided library has a function called `getAllPurchases` that when changed to `public` scope in the `Inventory` class is returning a `List` (currently empty because I can't purchase my own items)

My question is whether or not this `List` will show consumable purchases?

For example, I want to reward my users for ever having made any type of purchase through my app, but don't want to prevent them from making recurring purchases of this SKU item by restricting myself to using only non-consumables.

Thanks.